# Compare two columns in different dataframes, of types String and Array<string> respectively in pyspark without use explode function

Tags: pyspark

I have two dfs:

df1:

```
sku   category   cep   seller   state
4858    BDU     00000   xefd     SP
```

df2:

```
depth  price   sku  seller  infos_product
6.1    5.60  47347   gaha   [{1, 86800000, 86...
```

For df2 I have the follow schema:

```
 |-- depth: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sku: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- seller: string (nullable = true)
 |-- infos_produt: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- modality_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cep_coleta_ini: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cep_coleta_fim: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cep_entrega_ini: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cep_entrega_fim: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cubage_factor_entrega: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value_coleta: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value_entrega: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to do a check between these df's. Something like that:

```
condi = [(df1.seller_id == df2.seller) & (df2.infos_produt.state == df1.state)]

df_finish = (df1\
    .join(df2, on = condi ,how='left'))
```

But, return a error:

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(infos_produt.`state` = view.coverage_state)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(infos_produt.`state` = view.coverage_state)' (array<string> and string).
```

Can anyone help me?

PS: I would like resolve this problem without apply 'explode', because I have a big data and explode function don't work.

Comment: What do you mean "explode function don't work"? Are you getting any error or performance issue?

Comment: Where is `df1.infos_produt.state` in your `df1`? How about you displayed the entire column instead of `[{1, 86800000, 86...`?

Comment: @AzharKhan The explode fuction don't work ,because it runs for a long time without output :/

Comment: @wwnde, In my question already has the explanation. If you notice I put the df2 schema so you can see what is inside the 'infos_produt' field, in df1 there is no infos_produt, but there is the 'state' field. :)